# How to recursively call Where clause in Linq or SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

Let's say I have the following filter parameters:

```
Type="Student"  
School = "High"  
ReferenceID = "123abc"   
PaymentOnFile= "Y"
```

Now, I need to find 1st student based on these 4 parameters. If no students are found then I need to find them based on the 3 parameters, if no students are found then use 2 parameters, etc.

Here's my current code:

```
var Student = db.Students.Where(x=> x.School == School && x.Type == Type && x.ReferenceID == ReferenceID && x.PaymentOnFile == PaymentOnFile).FirstOrDefault();   
if (Student == null)
{
Student = db.Students.Where(x=> x.School == School && x.Type == Type && x.ReferenceID == ReferenceID).FirstOrDefault();
}
if (Student == null)
{
Student = db.Students.Where(x=> x.School == School && x.Type == Type).FirstOrDefault();
}
if (Student == null)
{
Student = db.Students.Where(x=> x.School == School).FirstOrDefault();
}

return Student;
```

This works but it is not very efficient and ugly. What is a better way to do this?  Maybe using expression trees or something else but I cannot figure it out.

SQL also works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
var student = db.Students
    .Where(x => x.School == school)
    .OrderBy(x => (x.Type == type) ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(x => (x.ReferenceID == referenceId) ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(x => (x.PaymentOnFile == paymentOnFile) ? 0 : 1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

This **dynamic** solution will perform **exactly** your recursive logic and will work at case of Linq and EF. You can add another conditions(to `predicates`, order matters), solution(`for` loop) will remain **the same**.

```
var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<Student, bool>>>
{
    x => x.School == "High",
    x => x.Type == "Student",
    x => x.ReferenceID == "123abc",
    x => x.PaymentOnFile == "Y",
};

Student student = null;
for(var i = 0; i < predicates.Count; i++)
{
    var query = db.Students.AsQueryable();
    for (var j = 0; j < predicates.Count - i; j++)            
        query = query.Where(predicates[j]);

    if ((student = query.FirstOrDefault()) != null)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting will check. Need to compare performace to the solution above.

Comment: @user194076 I think that performance will be better, because you should perform from one to three simple `Where` queries instead of three sorting with `case when` T-SQL constructions.

Answer (score 0):

i guess if you could apply this query logic which can help you better

```
SELECT      TOP 1 
            *
FROM        Student AS S
ORDER BY    CASE 
                WHEN S.School = @School AND S.[Type] = @Type AND S.ReferenceID = @ReferenceID AND S.PaymentOnFile = @PaymentOnFile THEN 
                    1 
                WHEN S.School = @School AND S.[Type] = @Type AND S.ReferenceID = @ReferenceID THEN 
                    2 
                WHEN S.School = @School AND S.[Type] = @Type THEN 
                    3 
                WHEN S.School = @School THEN 
                    4 
            END ASC
```